# How to use custom edge implementation with EdmondsKarp max flow algorithm

Tags: jgrapht, edmonds-karp

I'm trying to implement and simulate a network where I can try some routing methods.

My problem is that one of my routing methods is require me to calculate MaxFlow/MinCut.

I have a custom implementation for the edges, where I added some new fields like Capacity.
Here is my implementation:

```
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyDefaultWeightedEdge extends DefaultWeightedEdge implements Serializable {

    protected int freecapacity;
    protected boolean isFeasable;


    public MyDefaultWeightedEdge(){
        this.isFeasable = true;
    }

    protected int getFreeCapacity(){return this.freecapacity;}

    protected void setFreeCapacity(int i)
    {
        this.freecapacity = i;
    }

    protected boolean getFeasable(){return this.isFeasable;}

    protected void setFeasable(boolean b){this.isFeasable = b;}

    @Override
    protected Object getSource() {
        return super.getSource();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getTarget() {
        return super.getTarget();
    }

    @Override
    protected double getWeight(){

        System.out.println("getWeight");

        StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement e = stacktrace[2];//maybe this number needs to be corrected
        String methodName = e.getMethodName();

        if(methodName.equals(""))
        {
            return this.freecapacity;
        }
        else {
            return super.getWeight();
        }


    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.getSource() + " : " + this.getTarget() + ") " + "Weight " + this.getWeight() + " Capacity " + this.getFreeCapacity();
    }
}
```

When I try to use EdmondsKarpMFImpl my problem is that the algorithm uses the edgeweight as the capacity.

1. Question:
   How can I use my implementation of the edge?
2. Question:
   How can I get all of the edges which are in MinCut/MaxFlow ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different solutions.

1. Standard approach. If you only have 1 type of weight (e.g. a capacity, or a cost), you could simply use a `DefaultWeightedEdge` and use the graph's `setEdgeWeight` and `getEdgeWeight` methods to define the edge's weight. You are free to interpret this weight in whatever way that fits your application.

```
public static void exampleNF(){
    //Standard approach
    Graph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = new DefaultUndirectedWeightedGraph<>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);
    Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    Graphs.addEdge(graph, 1,2,10);
    Graphs.addEdge(graph, 2,3,4);
    Graphs.addEdge(graph, 2,4,3);
    Graphs.addEdge(graph, 1,4,8);
    Graphs.addEdge(graph, 4,3,15);
    MaximumFlowAlgorithm<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> mf = new EdmondsKarpMFImpl<>(graph);
    System.out.println(mf.getMaximumFlow(1,3));
}
```

2. Use an `AsWeightedGraph`. This is convenient if your graph doesn't have weights, or, if your edges have more than 1 weight (e.g. both a cost and a capacity) and you want to switch between them.

```
public static void exampleNF2(){
    //Make an unweighted graph weighted using an AsWeightedGraph wrapper
    Graph<Integer, DefaultEdge> graph = new DefaultUndirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    DefaultEdge e1 = graph.addEdge(1,2);
    DefaultEdge e2 = graph.addEdge(2,3);
    DefaultEdge e3 = graph.addEdge(2,4);
    DefaultEdge e4 = graph.addEdge(1,4);
    DefaultEdge e5 = graph.addEdge(4,3);

    Map<DefaultEdge, Double> capacities = Map.of(e1, 10.0, e2, 4.0, e3, 3.0, e4, 8.0, e5, 15.0);
    MaximumFlowAlgorithm<Integer, DefaultEdge> mf = new EdmondsKarpMFImpl<>(new AsWeightedGraph<>(graph, capacities));
    System.out.println(mf.getMaximumFlow(1,3));
}
```

3. Again using an `AsWeightedGraph`, but this time using a function as a 'pass-through' to get a specific weight stored on the arcs themselves

```
public static void exampleNF3(){
    //Using the AsWeightedGraph as a function
    Graph<Integer, MyEdge> graph = new DefaultUndirectedGraph<>(MyEdge.class);
    Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    graph.addEdge(1,2, new MyEdge(10));
    graph.addEdge(2,3, new MyEdge(4));
    graph.addEdge(2,4, new MyEdge(3));
    graph.addEdge(1,4, new MyEdge(8));
        graph.addEdge(4,3, new MyEdge(15));

    MaximumFlowAlgorithm<Integer, MyEdge> mf = new EdmondsKarpMFImpl<>(new AsWeightedGraph<>(graph, e -> e.capacity, false, false));
    System.out.println(mf.getMaximumFlow(1,3));
}

private static class MyEdge {
    private final double capacity;

    public MyEdge(double capacity){
        this.capacity=capacity;
    }
}
```

4. We could also implement our own custom graph and override the `getEdgeWeight` and `setEdgeWeight` methods. In this example, we use the `MyEdge` class from the previous example.

```
public static void exampleNF4(){
    //Using a custom graph
    MyGraph graph = new MyGraph(MyEdge.class);
    Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    graph.addEdge(1,2, new MyEdge(10));
    graph.addEdge(2,3, new MyEdge(4));
    graph.addEdge(2,4, new MyEdge(3));
    graph.addEdge(1,4, new MyEdge(8));
    graph.addEdge(4,3, new MyEdge(15));

    MaximumFlowAlgorithm<Integer, MyEdge> mf = new EdmondsKarpMFImpl<>(graph);
    System.out.println(mf.getMaximumFlow(1,3));
}

private static class MyGraph extends SimpleWeightedGraph<Integer, MyEdge>{
    public MyGraph(Class<? extends MyEdge> edgeClass) {
        super(edgeClass);
    }
    @Override
    public double getEdgeWeight(MyEdge e){
        return e.capacity;
    }
}
```

There's probably more, but this covers quite a range of different approaches already. Personally I would not implement my own graph class unless I need it for something very specific.